# Is it possible to have a regex in CSS Selector for tagname ?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to find elements using selenium webdriver with either `h2` or `h3` tag.

Is it possible to have a generic css selector for the above requirement ?

Something similar to `[tag^='h']` or `[att^=str]` ?

Comment: One way to do this could be `css = "h2, h3"`. Not sure though if it is correct .

Comment: your approach is correct

Comment: @hemanik: If all you want are h2 or h3 elements, then having a substring match for just ^h is *wrong* since that would match h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 and h6, not to mention header and hr too. In other words, yes, `css=h2, h3` is correct but more importantly, I don't know why you would choose anything else. This appears to be overengineering for its own sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For attributes, yes, you can. But for elements, you can have the possible values comma separated. [W3 CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```
Selector            Example              Description                                                                              CSS
element1,element2   h1,h2                Selects every <ul> element that are preceded by a <p> element                             3
[attribute~=value]  [title~=flower]       Selects all elements with a title attribute containing the word "flower"                 2
[attribute|=value]  [lang|=en]            Selects all elements with a lang attribute value starting with "en"                      2
[attribute^=value]  a[href^="https"]      Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value begins with "https"                 3
[attribute$=value]  a[href$=".pdf"]       Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value ends with ".pdf"                    3
[attribute*=value]  a[href*="w3schools"]  Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value contains the substring "w3schools"  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use comma-separated list of selectors. For your case use `h2, h3` selector. See [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping) for details.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer on question, but as additional option you also might use `XPath` that will match both elements by starting `"h"` letter:

```
//*[starts-with(name(), 'h')]
```

Comment: Thank you @Andersson for an alternative solution.

Comment: But this will also fetch all other elements which start with h for ex. HTML, HEAD , HEADER etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the most common example. OP might combine predicates to make `XPath` more specific and to fetch just requuired nodes